# Tring to print Hello World in Assembly with Virtual Studio

Tags: assembly, x86

I began to learn Assembly language by watching this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W3roB5sRg4o&list=PLRwVmtr-pp05c1HTBj1no6Fl6C6mlxYDG), in which we work on Visual Studio. As fas as I understand, here we run our Assembly code by using the C++ library for Win32 (I just have a poor knowledge on C language, and none on C++). So while writing assembly we keep open two files: `Mainer.cpp` and `MyAssembly.asm`.

`Mainer.cpp`:

```
extern "C" void doit();

void main()
{

    doit();

}
```

`MyAssembly.asm`:

```
.586
.model flat, c
.stack 100h

.data



.code
doit proc

doit endp

end
```

I've been playing around with what I've learned here and there and ultimately I wanted to print `'Hello, World'` (in the tutorial above that isn't done).  Here what I have:

```
.586
.model flat, c
.stack 100h

.data

    global  _main
    extern  _printf 

.code
doit proc

    _main:
    push    message
    call    _printf
    add     esp, 4
    ret
message:
    db  'Hello, World', 10, 0


doit endp

end
```

But when trying to debug I got the following errors:

> Error 1   error A2071: initializer magnitude too large for specified size
>
> Error 2   error : global  : error A2008
>
> Error 3   error A2071: initializer magnitude too large for specified size
>
> Error 4   error : in directive: error A2008
>
> Error 5   error A2071: initializer magnitude too large for specified size
>
> Error 6   error A2006: undefined symbol : _printf

Looking at the last error It seems that it is not link to the C library, but I don't know how to fix this.

I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

`.model flat,c` uses 'c' naming, so the underscore prefix is not needed. `push message` should be `push offset message` . `message` should be in data segment and without the `:` . Since there is a .cpp source (mainer.cpp), a default stack segment will be created, and the assembly code doesn't need to specify a stack segment.

```
        .586p
        .model  flat,c
        .data           ; initialized data
message db  'Hello, World', 10, 0
        .code           ; code
        extern  printf:near
doit    proc
        push    offset message
        call    printf
        add     esp, 4
        xor     eax,eax
        ret
doit    endp
        end
```